# PermissionError при записи в файл

Tags: python, windows, hosts

Записываю строки в файл `hosts` и получаю ошибку:

`Permission Error: [Errno 13] Permission denied`
Запускал и интерпретатор, и консоль от имени администратора, не помогает. Работаю и так под админом. Подскажите, что делать.

Comment: может антивирь перехватывает такую запись?

Comment: @Zergatul, мне кажется будет справедливо если __вы__ оформите это как ответ... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась добавлением в исключения антивируса самого скрипта.

Comment: У меня конкретно антивирус блокировал.

Comment: А ты точно от имени админа запускаешь cmd?

Comment: Это была моя ошибка. Всё работает.